# Office 365 Outlook, Calender removal

Tags: office-365

I have created some sites in office 365 sharepoint online however I want to remove the outlook, calender that seem to appear on all the sites.

What is the best way to remove these. Picture is attached.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can hide those using CSS.

Add following into the master page

```
#O365_MainLink_ShellMail #O365_MainLink_ShellCalendar {
    display:none;
}
```